# AVAssetWriter fails once App goes in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avassetwriter

I am working on iOS app in which i am creating video from images. I am using `AVAssetWriter` to achieve this. Everything works fine. But When app goes in background and switched back, the video writing fails. `AVAssetWriter`'s `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler` is not getting called when i switch back to app.

May be duplicate of [AVAssetWriter fails when Application enters Background during Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638078/avassetwriter-fails-when-application-enters-background-during-rendering) , but i am not getting any help from there.

Any idea for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you setup a background processing task? Your question lacks detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that you want the video to continue rendering while in the background.

I fixed this in my app doing by asking the OS to grant the app background task permisions (for a limited amount of time). This answer might help you too 
[iOS generating a video in the background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163372/ios-generating-a-video-in-the-background-task/16165204#16165204)

```
    @property (nonatomic,assign) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier __block backgroundRenderingID;

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    _backgroundRenderingID = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:_backgroundRenderingID];
        _backgroundRenderingID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
```

Don't forget to let go once you are done!

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_backgroundRenderingID];
```